# Write a test to find all types used in the instantiation of a class

Tags: c#, reflection, typeof

I have some code like:

```
new ValidationFailure<AddSystemUserDto>
```

This is in various places in my application service layer, I want to find all the different "Dto" types that have been used when newing up a ValidationFailure across the code, is this possible using reflection? Without having to run each application service method?

Comment: _"is this possible using reflection"_ - probably, but that would require you to dig through all methods, and also find all `public void Foo<TBar>() { return new ValidationFailure<TBar>(); }` and calls to that method, ad nauseum. You'd rather do this before or at compile-time, using static analysis, for example through ReSharper or Roslyn. You definitely don't want to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

I use a little helper class for these kinds of tasks, that I conveniently call `Decompiler`. Basically it transforms a byte[] of .NET code to opcodes:

```
public class ILInstruction
{
    public ILInstruction(int offset, OpCode code, object operand)
    {
        this.Offset = offset;
        this.Code = code;
        this.Operand = operand;
    }

    // Fields
    public int Offset { get; private set; }
    public OpCode Code { get; private set; }
    public object Operand { get; private set; }
}

internal class Decompiler
{
    private Decompiler() { }

    static Decompiler()
    {
        InitDecompiler();
    }

    private static OpCode[] singleByteOpcodes;
    private static OpCode[] multiByteOpcodes;

    private static void InitDecompiler()
    {
        singleByteOpcodes = new OpCode[0x100];
        multiByteOpcodes = new OpCode[0x100];
        FieldInfo[] infoArray1 = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields();
        for (int num1 = 0; num1 < infoArray1.Length; num1++)
        {
            FieldInfo info1 = infoArray1[num1];
            if (info1.FieldType == typeof(OpCode))
            {
                OpCode code1 = (OpCode)info1.GetValue(null);
                ushort num2 = (ushort)code1.Value;
                if (num2 < 0x100)
                {
                    singleByteOpcodes[(int)num2] = code1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((num2 & 0xff00) != 0xfe00)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Invalid opcode: " + num2.ToString());
                    }
                    multiByteOpcodes[num2 & 0xff] = code1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ILInstruction> Decompile(MethodBase mi, byte[] ildata)
    {
        Module module = mi.Module;

        ByteReader reader = new ByteReader(ildata);
        while (!reader.Eof)
        {
            OpCode code = OpCodes.Nop;

            int offset = reader.Position;
            ushort b = reader.ReadByte();
            if (b != 0xfe)
            {
                code = singleByteOpcodes[b];
            }
            else
            {
                b = reader.ReadByte();
                code = multiByteOpcodes[b];
                b |= (ushort)(0xfe00);
            }

            object operand = null;
            switch (code.OperandType)
            {
                case OperandType.InlineBrTarget:
                    operand = reader.ReadInt32() + reader.Position;
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineField:
                    if (mi is ConstructorInfo)
                    {
                        operand = module.ResolveField(reader.ReadInt32(), mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments(), Type.EmptyTypes);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        operand = module.ResolveField(reader.ReadInt32(), mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments(), mi.GetGenericArguments());
                    }
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineI:
                    operand = reader.ReadInt32();
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineI8:
                    operand = reader.ReadInt64();
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineMethod:
                    try
                    {
                        if (mi is ConstructorInfo)
                        {
                            operand = module.ResolveMember(reader.ReadInt32(), mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments(), Type.EmptyTypes);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            operand = module.ResolveMember(reader.ReadInt32(), mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments(), mi.GetGenericArguments());
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        operand = null;
                    }
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineNone:
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineR:
                    operand = reader.ReadDouble();
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineSig:
                    operand = module.ResolveSignature(reader.ReadInt32());
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineString:
                    operand = module.ResolveString(reader.ReadInt32());
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineSwitch:
                    int count = reader.ReadInt32();
                    int[] targetOffsets = new int[count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    {
                        targetOffsets[i] = reader.ReadInt32();
                    }
                    int pos = reader.Position;
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    {
                        targetOffsets[i] += pos;
                    }
                    operand = targetOffsets;
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineTok:
                case OperandType.InlineType:
                    try
                    {
                        if (mi is ConstructorInfo)
                        {
                            operand = module.ResolveMember(reader.ReadInt32(), mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments(), Type.EmptyTypes);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            operand = module.ResolveMember(reader.ReadInt32(), mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments(), mi.GetGenericArguments());
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        operand = null;
                    }
                    break;
                case OperandType.InlineVar:
                    operand = reader.ReadUInt16();
                    break;
                case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget:
                    operand = reader.ReadSByte() + reader.Position;
                    break;
                case OperandType.ShortInlineI:
                    operand = reader.ReadSByte();
                    break;
                case OperandType.ShortInlineR:
                    operand = reader.ReadSingle();
                    break;
                case OperandType.ShortInlineVar:
                    operand = reader.ReadByte();
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unknown instruction operand; cannot continue. Operand type: " + code.OperandType);
            }

            yield return new ILInstruction(offset, code, operand);
        }
    }
}
```

From this point, the rest is a matter of finding all types that you use when calling constructors (Note: untested code, there's probably something wrong :-):

```
IEnumerable<Type> FindDtoTypes()
{
foreach (var item in GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()) 
{
    foreach (var member in type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        var meth = member as MethodBase;
        if (meth != null && meth.GetMethodBody() != null)
        {
            var code = meth.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
            foreach (var instr in Decompile(meth, code))
            {
                var oper = instr.Operand as MethodBase;
                if (oper != null && oper.IsConstructor &&
                    oper.DeclaringType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    var dtoType = mb.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments().First();

                    if (dtoType.IsAssignableFrom(oper.DeclaringType))
                        yield return oper.DeclaringType;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```